# Relative addressing

Tags: html, apache, url, relative-path

I have developed a web site that contains folders for each theme (Admin,Contact,Message).  The root directory contains an file that I use as the menu bar and are rendered on each page. Anytime I navigate from one page to another page in a different folder, Apache adds the folder name of the previous folder to the current folder. Eg. If I am on page /Admin/Test.hml and move to Contact.html which happens to be in the Contact folder, the url becomes /Admin/Contact/Contact.html instead of /Contact/Contact.html  How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of relative and absolute paths.
Have a look at this nice article: http://www.uvsc.edu/disted/decourses/dgm/2120/IN/steinja/lessons/06/06_04.html
or this one
http://kb.worldsecuresystems.com/165/bc_1653.html